# Validating url format in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I had an text field where user has to place an url. I need to validate the url whether format is valid.I need to write an reg-exp to find below invalid urls.

```
http://www.google.com//test/index.html //Because of double slash after host name

http:/www.google.com/test/index.html //Missing double slash for protocol
```

I tried below code which is working for second case but not for first case

```
function test(url) {
    var exp=/^(https?:\/\/)?((([a-z\d]([a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])*)\.)+[a-z]{2,}|((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}))(\:\d+)?(\/[-a-z\d%_.~+]*)*(\?[;&a-z\d%_.~+=-]*)?(\#[-a-z\d_]*)?$/;
    return exp.test(url);
}

var firstCase="http://www.google.com//test/index.html";

alert(test(firstCase));

var secondCase = "http:/www.google.com/test/index.html";

alert(test(secondCase ));

var thirdCase="http://www.google.com/test//index.html";

alert(test(thirdCase));
```

Comment: [Its working fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Nsisodia91/gqwvLze2/). Can you please elaborate whats not working over here

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

Comment: Try this tool: https://regex101.com/  It will allow you to see which sections are matching.

Comment: Two slashes are usually treated as a single one, also, you should account for other protocols, like mailto, ftp...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: `//` is a valid path. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki///

Answer (score 0):

This  regex fixes your issue, the "/" needs a question mark after it, to indicate zero or one of those, it was previously grouped with a * element menaing mulitple were allowed

```
function test(url) {
    var exp=/^(https?:\/\/)?((([a-z\d]([a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])*)\.)+[a-z]{2,}|((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}))(\:\d+)?(\/?)([-a-z\d%_.~+]*)*(\?[;&a-z\d%_.~+=-]*)?(\#[-a-z\d_]*)?$/;
    return exp.test(url);
}

alert(test("http://www.google.com//bla")); //false
alert(test("http:/www.google.com/test/index.html")); //false
alert(test("http://www.google.com/bla")); //true
```

To be more specific: the slash in the first group here `(\/?)([-a-z\d%_.~+]*)`  was prevoiusly inside the second group, and was therefore allowed multiple times

Comment: alert(test("http://www.google.com/bla/index.html")); //true .. This url is valid but expression is giving false.

Comment: that might be the case, but that was not your specific problem, the url-validation has many more problems than this